# Accessing HTML DOM from Mono WebBrowser control?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mono, webbrowser-control

Using .NET's Webbrowser control for Windows Forms , it is pretty easy to access the DOM. Consider this scenario

```
this.webBrowser1.Navigate
            (Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath,"TestPage.html"));
```

Now, Assume that you've a test javascript method in your html page, which accepts a string param. So, once loading is complete, you may

```
webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("test", new object[] { "hi" });
```

Now, I'm trying running this in Mono. At Runtime, Mono should be using Mono's web browser control - http://www.mono-project.com/WebBrowser. I am finding some very weird behavior (see the update)

Question is, how to access the HTML DOM, probably to invoke a script, via Mono's webbrowser control?

**Update**

Just noted that webBrowser1.Document is null only when I'm connected to the network. Otherwise, if I'm offline, the script is actually getting invoked, but then the Mono runtime crashes after that, with this error

Stacktrace:

```
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Mono.Mozilla.Base.gluezilla_evalScript (intptr,string) <0x00004>    
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Mono.Mozilla.Base.gluezilla_evalScript (intptr,string) <0x00004>    
  at Mono.Mozilla.Base.EvalScript (Mono.WebBrowser.IWebBrowser,string) <IL 0x0001a, 0x00038>    
  at Mono.Mozilla.DOM.Document.InvokeScript (string) <IL 0x00007, 0x00017>    
  at System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument.InvokeScript (string,object[]) [0x00054] in C:\cygwin\tmp\monobuild\build\BUILD\mono-2.6.7\mcs\class\Managed.Windows.Forms\System.Windows.Forms\HtmlDocument.cs:143    
  at WindowsFormsHost.Form1.ShowMsg (string) <IL 0x0002b, 0x000ac>    
  at WindowsFormsHost.Form1.testToolStripMenuItem_Click (object,System.EventArgs) <IL 0x00008, 0x0001c>    
  at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.OnClick (System.EventArgs) [0x0001c] in C:\cygwin\tmp\monobuild\build\BUILD\mono-2.6.7\mcs\class\Managed.Windows.Forms\System.Windows.Forms\ToolStripItem.cs:1002    
  at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem.OnClick (System.EventArgs) [0x000a5] in C:\cygwin\tmp\monobuild\build\BUILD\mono-2.6.7\mcs\class\Managed.Windows.Forms\System.Windows.Forms\ToolStripMenuItem.cs:267    
  at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem.HandleClick (System.EventArgs) [0x00000] in C:\cygwin\tmp\monobuild\build\BUILD\mono-2.6.7\mcs\class\Managed.Windows.Forms\System.Windows.Forms\ToolStripMenuItem.cs:539    
  at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.FireEvent (System.EventArgs,System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemEventType) [0x00042] in C:\cygwin\tmp\monobuild\build\BUILD\mono-2.6.7\mcs\class\Managed.Windows.Forms\System.Windows.Forms\ToolStripItem.cs:1776    
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.FireEvent (System.EventArgs,System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemEventType) <IL 0x00034, 0x00061>    
  at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.OnMouseUp (System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) [0x00047] in C:\cygwin\tmp\monobuild\build\BUILD\mono-2.6.7\mcs\class\Managed.Windows.Forms\System.Windows.Forms\ToolStrip.cs:960    
  at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown.OnMouseUp (System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) [0x00000] in C:\cygwin\tmp\monobuild\build\BUILD\mono-2.6.7\mcs\class\Managed.Windows.Forms\System.Windows.Forms\ToolStripDropDown.cs:630    
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmLButtonUp (System.Windows.Forms.Message&) [0x0007e] in C:\cygwin\tmp\monobuild\build\BUILD\mono-2.6.7\mcs\class\Managed.Windows.Forms\System.Windows.Forms\Control.cs:5592    
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc (System.Windows.Forms.Message&) [0x0017b] in C:\cygwin\tmp\monobuild\build\BUILD\mono-2.6.7\mcs\class\Managed.Windows.Forms\System.Windows.Forms\Control.cs:5329    
  at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc (System.Windows.Forms.Message&) [0x00000] in C:\cygwin\tmp\monobuild\build\BUILD\mono-2.6.7\mcs\class\Managed.Windows.Forms\System.Windows.Forms\ScrollableControl.cs:807    
  at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.WndProc (System.Windows.Forms.Message&) [0x00000] in C:\cygwin\tmp\monobuild\build\BUILD\mono-2.6.7\mcs\class\Managed.Windows.Forms\System.Windows.Forms\ToolStrip.cs:1213    
  at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown.WndProc (System.Windows.Forms.Message&) [0x0001a] in C:\cygwin\tmp\monobuild\build\BUILD\mono-2.6.7\mcs\class\Managed.Windows.Forms\System.Windows.Forms\ToolStripDropDown.cs:722    
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control/ControlWindowTarget.OnMessage (System.Windows.Forms.Message&) [0x00000] in C:\cygwin\tmp\monobuild\build\BUILD\mono-2.6.7\mcs\class\Managed.Windows.Forms\System.Windows.Forms\Control.cs:234    
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control/ControlNativeWindow.WndProc (System.Windows.Forms.Message&) [0x00000] in C:\cygwin\tmp\monobuild\build\BUILD\mono-2.6.7\mcs\class\Managed.Windows.Forms\System.Windows.Forms\Control.cs:215    
  at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.WndProc (intptr,System.Windows.Forms.Msg,intptr,intptr) [0x00085] in C:\cygwin\tmp\monobuild\build\BUILD\mono-2.6.7\mcs\class\Managed.Windows.Forms\System.Windows.Forms\NativeWindow.cs:242    
  at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUIWin32.InternalWndProc (intptr,System.Windows.Forms.Msg,intptr,intptr) [0x00031] in C:\cygwin\tmp\monobuild\build\BUILD\mono-2.6.7\mcs\class\Managed.Windows.Forms\System.Windows.Forms\XplatUIWin32.cs:1946    
  at (wrapper native-to-managed) System.Windows.Forms.XplatUIWin32.InternalWndProc (intptr,System.Windows.Forms.Msg,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00021, 0x00073>    
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Windows.Forms.XplatUIWin32.Win32DispatchMessage (System.Windows.Forms.MSG&) <0x00004>    
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Windows.Forms.XplatUIWin32.Win32DispatchMessage (System.Windows.Forms.MSG&) <0x00004>    
  at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUIWin32.DispatchMessage (System.Windows.Forms.MSG&) [0x00000] in C:\cygwin\tmp\monobuild\build\BUILD\mono-2.6.7\mcs\class\Managed.Windows.Forms\System.Windows.Forms\XplatUIWin32.cs:2146    
  at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUI.DispatchMessage (System.Windows.Forms.MSG&) [0x00000] in C:\cygwin\tmp\monobuild\build\BUILD\mono-2.6.7\mcs\class\Managed.Windows.Forms\System.Windows.Forms\XplatUI.cs:605    
  at System.Windows.Forms.Application.RunLoop (bool,System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext) [0x0036a] in C:\cygwin\tmp\monobuild\build\BUILD\mono-2.6.7\mcs\class\Managed.Windows.Forms\System.Windows.Forms\Application.cs:984
  at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run (System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext) [0x00014] in C:\cygwin\tmp\monobuild\build\BUILD\mono-2.6.7\mcs\class\Managed.Windows.Forms\System.Windows.Forms\Application.cs:763
  at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run (System.Windows.Forms.Form) [0x00000] in C:\cygwin\tmp\monobuild\build\BUILD\mono-2.6.7\mcs\class\Managed.Windows.Forms\System.Windows.Forms\Application.cs:742
  at WindowsFormsHost.Program.Main () <IL 0x00013, 0x00044>
  at (wrapper runtime-invoke) object.runtime_invoke_void (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x0001b, 0x0003a>
```

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.

Answer (score 2):

It should work, but unfortunately things break much more than I would like every time mozilla throws up an update. Are you doing this on windows or linux? What xulrunner version do you have installed?

Comment: This issue was on Windows, Mono version 2.6.7 - Will get back after checking Xulrunner version. Thanks